# Good example of react project to see folder structure

Tags: reactjs, repository

As I get used to React, I want to see good examples of React projects to learn from its coding style, folder structure, etc.

If you know any good projects, can you leave links to those repositories?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should browse some examples in the following places:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app (this is the best place to start, they give you a running React App out the box and then you can go figure how you like)

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ another good option, slightly more advanced than CRA. it offers some extra features

https://nextjs.org/ this is another good option. they offer stuff out the box like server side rendering

Personally if you are new to React, I would start with Create React App. It will give you a good feel for the basics of a React project and allow you to get your own app up and running. It comes with `Jest` built in so you can start writing and building tests from the off.

this is also a good blog post: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html if you want to read more about how React apps can be structured

Comment: I am not new to react, in fact quite used to it as i mentioned in my question. I did start off with create-react-app but as my project grows in size, i wanted to reorganize my folder structure and etc. I tried to find some react projects on github but my searching skill on github wasnt good enough to do so.

Comment: So if you know any projects that have good implementation of reactJS, please let me know! (not starting template)

Comment: @J.S.C how about this? https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-folder-structure let me know if that is good, I think it is

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for

Comment: no worries mate. happy to help. will upvote your question now!